# Intersection Of Topologies that contain a particular basis

Tags: general-topology

$Question:$

If $\mathscr A$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, then the topology generated by $\mathscr A$ equals the intersection of all the topologies that contain $\mathscr A$

$ My Approach:$

$\{ \mathscr T_\alpha\} $ be a class of topologies containing $\mathscr A$

From the given condition,

$\mathscr A \subseteq \mathscr T_\alpha$  $\forall \alpha$

$\Rightarrow$ $\mathscr T _ {\mathscr A}\subseteq \mathscr T_\alpha  $  $\forall \alpha $, where  $\mathscr T _ {\mathscr A}$ is the topology generated by $\mathscr A$

$\Rightarrow$ 
$\mathscr T _ {\mathscr A}\subseteq \bigcap \mathscr T_\alpha  $

Now how do I show

$\bigcap\mathscr T_\alpha\subseteq$ $\mathscr T _ {\mathscr A}$

Comment: @bof: In my experience the more common definition is the one given by **Aweygan**.

Comment: @bof $\mathscr T_ {\mathscr A}$ contains all the union of all the elements of $\mathscr A$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're the expert, so I'll add this to the list of basic (unintended pun) things I've been misinformed about all my life. I would have thought that "topology generated by $\mathscr S$" would be defined and would be a topology for any choice of $\mathscr S,$ not necessarily a base as in this question.

Comment: @bof: I think that it’s probably at least in part a matter of pædagogy combined with the fact that bases are more important in practice than subbases. If you start with metric spaces, bases of $\epsilon$-balls are very natural, and you generalize to open sets as unions thereof. If, as I prefer, you start with topologies, you still want bases early on, because many topologies are hard to define any other way. Subbases tend to be brought in last, and then you usually define the base generated by a subbase and use it to generate the topology. The result here, for bases or subbases, tends to ...

Comment: ... left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathscr{T}_{\mathscr{A}}$ is itself one of the $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$ in your collection.

Comment: This observation directly leads to the conclusion. Thank you!